# Не работает __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Допустим у меня есть такая директория:

```
project/SomeDirectory/Test.py
```

И в папке `Project` есть файл `module.py`

```
project/module.py
```

И мне нужно из `Test.py` импортировать `module.py`. 
При этом, в `Project` также есть `__init__.py`

Получается такая директория:

```
project:
  SomeDirectory:
    Test.py
  module.py
  __init__.py
```

В файле `Test.py` такой код:

```
from project import module.py
```

Я запускаю код и он мне выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\project\SomeDirectory\Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from project import module
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Вероятно, вы не можете импортировать пакеты - выше по пути.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте **main.py**, положите его рядом с **module.py** и папке `project`
и запустите его.

**main.py**

```
import os

print(f'\nHello main.py')
print(f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}")

from SomeDirectory import Test
```

**Test.py**

```
import os

print(f'\nHello Test.py')
print(f'dir = {os.path.dirname(__file__)}')

import module as md

rez = md.func()
print(rez)
```

**module.py**

```
import os

print(f'\nHello module.py')
print(f'dir = {os.path.dirname(__file__)}')

def func():
    text = '\nHello def func(): module.py'
    return text
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за уделённое время!

Comment: @ElectroN4ick пожалуйста